# Creating unique slug using title of post

Tags: php, slug

I have an add post form to add new post. I have taken post title as post_url or slug. I want unique post_url.
Here is what I have done so far -

```
$post_name = $this->input->post('post_title');
function clean($post_name) {
    $name = trim($post_name);
    $post_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $name);
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $post_name);
}

$post_url = clean($post_name);
$query = mysql_query("select post_url from sa_posts where post_url like '" . $post_url . "%'");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $slugs[] = $r['post_url'];
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0 && in_array($post_url, $slugs)) {
        $max = 0;
        while (in_array(($post_url . '-' . ++$max), $slugs)) ;
        $post_url .= '-' . $max;
    }
}
echo "Slug " . $post_url;
```

I am getting output as -

> post-url
>
> post-url-1
>
> post-url-1-1
>
> post-url-1-1-1

**But I want output as -**

> post-url
>
> post-url-1
>
> post-url-2
>
> post-url-3

What is a problem in my code?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: first change $post_url .= '-' . $max; to $post_url =  $post_url. $max;

Comment: @coder It is just removing hyphen(-) and showing output as post-url, post-url1, post-url2

Comment: plz check the ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code in the following way

```
$post_url = clean($post_name);
$post_url1 = $post_url;
$query = mysql_query("select post_url from sa_posts where post_url like '" . $post_url . "%'");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $slugs[] = $r['post_url'];
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0 && in_array($post_url, $slugs)) {
        $max = 0;
        $post_url = $post_url1;
        while (in_array(($post_url . '-' . ++$max), $slugs)) ;
        $post_url .= '-' . $max;
    }
}
echo "Slug " . $post_url;
```

Comment: @ coder This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
function UniqueSlugGenerator($p){
    include("conn.php");
    $RowCou=0;
    $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '-', strtolower(trim(strip_tags($p))));
    $qq = mysqli_query($conn,"select Slug from ser_posts where Slug like '$slug%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $RowCou = mysqli_num_rows($qq);
    return ($RowCou > 0) ? $slug.'-'.(++$RowCou) : $slug;
}
```